# Display Total in ASP.Net GridView in C# and show with grouping

Tags: c#, gridview

How to show a table in GridView by using c#
[**Output Result**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BqUi.jpg)

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - otherwise, it is very difficult to help you.

Comment: And what code you have written for this?

Comment: are you trying to do it on webform? or window application? if it is on web, i think you can implement it by using html code. Otherwise i don't think you can do something like that in win application and you properly need to create custom user control using webBrowser.

Answer (score 0):

**This is asp.net code**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <style>
        .SubTotalRowStyle {
            border: solid 1px Black;
            background-color: #81BEF7;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .GrandTotalRowStyle {
            border: solid 1px Black;
            background-color: Gray;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .GroupHeaderStyle {
            border: solid 1px Black;
            background-color: #81BEF7;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .ExpandCollapseStyle {
            border: 0px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .ExpandCollapseGrandStyle {
            border: 0px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
    <link href="Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:GridView ID="grdViewOrders" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" TabIndex="1"
                Width="100%" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1" CssClass="grdViewOrders"
                CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical"
                OnRowDataBound="grdViewOrders_RowDataBound"
                OnRowCreated="grdViewOrders_RowCreated" BackColor="White"
                BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                        <ItemStyle Width="10px" />
                        <ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                        <ItemStyle Width="10px" />
                        <ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderID" HeaderText="OrderID">
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="ProductName">
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="UnitPrice" HeaderText="UnitPrice">
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Quantity" HeaderText="Quantity">
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Discount" HeaderText="Discount">
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Amount" HeaderText="Amount">
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:BoundField>
                </Columns>
                <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="Black" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="Black" />
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="Black" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FBFBF2" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#848384" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#EAEAD3" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#575357" />
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="Data/Orders.xml"></asp:XmlDataSource>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //ExpandCollapse
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.ExpandCollapseStyle').click(function () {

                var orderId = $(this).attr('alt');

                if (!isDisplayed($('.ExpandCollapse' + orderId))) {
                    $(this).attr('src', 'images/minus.gif');
                    $('.ExpandCollapse' + orderId).css("display", "block");
                }
                else {
                    $(this).attr('src', 'images/plus.gif');
                    $('.ExpandCollapse' + orderId).css("display", "none");
                }
            })
            $('.ExpandCollapseGrandStyle').click(function () {

                $(".grdViewOrders tr").each(function () {

                    var orderId = $(this).find(".ExpandCollapseStyle").attr('alt');

                    if (orderId != 'undefined') {

                        if ($(this).attr('alt') == 'Expanded') {

                            $(this).find(".ExpandCollapseStyle").attr('src', 'images/minus.gif');
                            $('.ExpandCollapse' + orderId).css("display", "block");
                            $(this).attr('alt', 'Collapsed');

                        }
                        else {

                            $(this).find(".ExpandCollapseStyle").attr('src', 'images/plus.gif');
                            $('.ExpandCollapse' + orderId).css("display", "none");
                            $(this).attr('alt', 'Expanded');

                        }
                    }
                });
                if ($('.ExpandCollapseGrandStyle').attr('alt') == 'Expanded') {
                    $('.ExpandCollapseGrandStyle').attr('src', 'images/plus.gif');
                    $('.ExpandCollapseGrandStyle').attr('alt', 'Collapsed');
                }
                else {
                    $('.ExpandCollapseGrandStyle').attr('src', 'images/minus.gif');
                    $('.ExpandCollapseGrandStyle').attr('alt', 'Expanded');
                }
            })
            function isDisplayed(object) {
                // if the object is visible return true
                if ($(object).css('display') == 'block') {
                    return true;
                }
                // if the object is not visible return false
                return false;
            };
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**This is c#**

```
// To keep track of the previous row Group Identifier
string strPreviousRowID = string.Empty;
// To keep track the Index of Group Total
int intSubTotalIndex = 1;

string strGroupHeaderText = string.Empty;

// To temporarily store Sub Total
double dblSubTotalUnitPrice = 0;
double dblSubTotalQuantity = 0;
double dblSubTotalDiscount = 0;
double dblSubTotalAmount = 0;

// To temporarily store Grand Total
double dblGrandTotalUnitPrice = 0;
double dblGrandTotalQuantity = 0;
double dblGrandTotalDiscount = 0;
double dblGrandTotalAmount = 0;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
/// <summary>
/// Event fires for every row creation
/// Used for creating SubTotal row when next group starts by adding Group Total at previous row manually
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
protected void grdViewOrders_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    bool IsSubTotalRowNeedToAdd = false;
    bool IsGrandTotalRowNeedtoAdd = false;

    if ((strPreviousRowID != string.Empty) && (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "CustomerID") != null))
        if (strPreviousRowID != DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "CustomerID").ToString())
            IsSubTotalRowNeedToAdd = true;

    if ((strPreviousRowID != string.Empty) && (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "CustomerID") == null))
    {
        IsSubTotalRowNeedToAdd = true;
        IsGrandTotalRowNeedtoAdd = true;
        intSubTotalIndex = 0;
    }

    #region Getting the first Group Header Text
    if ((strPreviousRowID == string.Empty) && (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "CustomerID") != null))
        strGroupHeaderText = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "CompanyName").ToString();

    #endregion

    if (IsSubTotalRowNeedToAdd)
    {
        #region Adding Sub Total Row
        GridView grdViewOrders = (GridView)sender;

        // Creating a Row
        GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.DataRow, DataControlRowState.Insert);

        //Adding Group Expand Collapse Cell 
        TableCell cell = new TableCell();
        row.Cells.Add(cell);

        //Adding Expand Collapse Cell 
        cell = new TableCell();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlImage img = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlImage();
        img.Src = "images/minus.gif";
        img.Attributes.Add("alt", strPreviousRowID);
        img.Attributes.Add("class", "ExpandCollapseStyle");
        cell.Controls.Add(img);
        cell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
        cell.CssClass = "SubTotalRowStyle";
        row.Cells.Add(cell);

        //Adding Header Cell 
        cell = new TableCell();
        cell.Text = strGroupHeaderText;
        cell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
        cell.ColumnSpan = 2;
        cell.CssClass = "SubTotalRowStyle";
        row.Cells.Add(cell);

        //Adding Unit Price Column
        cell = new TableCell();
        cell.Text = string.Format("{0:0.00}", dblSubTotalUnitPrice);
        cell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
        cell.CssClass = "SubTotalRowStyle";
        row.Cells.Add(cell);

        //Adding Quantity Column
        cell = new TableCell();
        cell.Text = string.Format("{0:0.00}", dblSubTotalQuantity);
        cell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
        cell.CssClass = "SubTotalRowStyle";
        row.Cells.Add(cell);

        //Adding Discount Column
        cell = new TableCell();
        cell.Text = string.Format("{0:0.00}", dblSubTotalDiscount);
        cell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
        cell.CssClass = "SubTotalRowStyle";
        row.Cells.Add(cell);

        //Adding Amount Column
        cell = new TableCell();
        cell.Text = string.Format("{0:0.00}", dblSubTotalAmount);
        cell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
        cell.CssClass = "SubTotalRowStyle";
        row.Cells.Add(cell);

        //Adding the Row at the RowIndex position in the Grid
        grdViewOrders.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(e.Row.RowIndex + intSubTotalIndex, row);
        intSubTotalIndex++;
        #endregion

        #region Getting Next Group Header Details
        if (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "CustomerID") != null)
            strGroupHeaderText = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "CompanyName").ToString();
        #endregion

        #region Reseting the Sub Total Variables
        dblSubTotalUnitPrice = 0;
        dblSubTotalQuantity = 0;
        dblSubTotalDiscount = 0;
        dblSubTotalAmount = 0;
        #endregion
    }
    if (IsGrandTotalRowNeedtoAdd)
    {
        #region Grand Total Row
        GridView grdViewOrders = (GridView)sender;

        // Creating a Row
        GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.DataRow, DataControlRowState.Insert);

        //Adding Group Expand Collapse Cell 
        TableCell cell = new TableCell();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlImage img = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlImage();
        img.Src = "images/minus.gif";
        img.Attributes.Add("class", "ExpandCollapseGrandStyle");
        img.Attributes.Add("alt", "Expanded");
        cell.Controls.Add(img);
        cell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
        cell.CssClass = "GrandTotalRowStyle";
        row.Cells.Add(cell);

        //Adding Expand Collapse Cell 
        cell = new TableCell();
        cell.CssClass = "GrandTotalRowStyle";
        row.Cells.Add(cell);

        //Adding Header Cell 
        cell = new TableCell();
        cell.Text = "Grand Total";
        cell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
        cell.ColumnSpan = 2;
        cell.CssClass = "GrandTotalRowStyle";
        row.Cells.Add(cell);

        //Adding Unit Price Column
        cell = new TableCell();
        cell.Text = string.Format("{0:0.00}", dblGrandTotalUnitPrice);
        cell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
        cell.CssClass = "GrandTotalRowStyle";
        row.Cells.Add(cell);

        //Adding Quantity Column
        cell = new TableCell();
        cell.Text = string.Format("{0:0.00}", dblGrandTotalQuantity);
        cell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
        cell.CssClass = "GrandTotalRowStyle";
        row.Cells.Add(cell);

        //Adding Discount Column
        cell = new TableCell();
        cell.Text = string.Format("{0:0.00}", dblGrandTotalDiscount);
        cell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
        cell.CssClass = "GrandTotalRowStyle";
        row.Cells.Add(cell);

        //Adding Amount Column
        cell = new TableCell();
        cell.Text = string.Format("{0:0.00}", dblGrandTotalAmount);
        cell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
        cell.CssClass = "GrandTotalRowStyle";
        row.Cells.Add(cell);

        //Adding the Row at the RowIndex position in the Grid
        grdViewOrders.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(e.Row.RowIndex, row);
        #endregion
    }
}
/// <summary>
/// Event fires when data binds to each row
/// Used for calculating Group Total 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
protected void grdViewOrders_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    // This is for cumulating the values
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        strPreviousRowID = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "CustomerID").ToString();

        double dblUnitPrice = Convert.ToDouble(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "UnitPrice").ToString());
        double dblQuantity = Convert.ToDouble(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Quantity").ToString());
        double dblDiscount = Convert.ToDouble(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Discount").ToString());
        double dblAmount = Convert.ToDouble(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Amount").ToString());

        // Cumulating Sub Total
        dblSubTotalUnitPrice += dblUnitPrice;
        dblSubTotalQuantity += dblQuantity;
        dblSubTotalDiscount += dblDiscount;
        dblSubTotalAmount += dblAmount;

        // Cumulating Grand Total
        dblGrandTotalUnitPrice += dblUnitPrice;
        dblGrandTotalQuantity += dblQuantity;
        dblGrandTotalDiscount += dblDiscount;
        dblGrandTotalAmount += dblAmount;

        e.Row.Style.Add("display", "block");
        e.Row.CssClass = "ExpandCollapse" + strPreviousRowID;
    }

}
```